# Network interface is missing, there is no driver in lspci

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, drivers, network-interface

On some Linux host Ethernet interface `eno1` suddenly disappeared after rebooting.
When I do `lspci -vmmmk` and search for "eth" I see several devices, one of them having no `Driver:` line.

Partial output:

```
Slot: 3d:00.0
...
Vendor: Intel Corporation
Device: Device 37cc
...
SDevice: Device 0000
Rev:09
NUMANode: 0
```

There are no `Driver:` or `Module:` lines here. What does this mean?

P.S. In the `ip l` output some order numbers are missed. It's something like:

```
1:..
2:..
3:..
6:..
```

Sorry, if it's obvious.

Comment: Did you updated your system or made some modifications that could have trigger this behaviour ?

Comment: @binarym Some hardware was plugged on the eve. But there were no kernel upgrades..